# email__iexact on django doesn't work on postgresql?

Tags: django, postgresql

Calling `UserModel.objects.filter(email__iexact=email)` results in the following query

```
SELECT * FROM "accounts_person" WHERE "accounts_person"."email" = UPPER('my-email@mail.com')
```

This doesn't find anything because it there's no `EMAIL@MAIL.COM` in the database, only `email@mail.com`. Shouldn't the query have been translated to
`WHERE UPPER("accounts_person"."email") = UPPER('my-email@mail.com')`?

Summary:

```
UserModel.objects.filter(email=email) # works
UserModel.objects.filter(email__exact=email) # works
UserModel.objects.filter(email__iexact=email) # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I had patched `lookup_cast` to be able to use the unaccent module on postgresql and ended up not calling the original `lookup_cast` afterwards. The generated query now looks like this `WHERE UPPER("accounts_person"."email"::text) = UPPER('my-email@mail.com')`. This is the default behavior on django.

Answer (score 1):

Clash you ae right this i also faced the same situtaion with postgres sql .

If you go through [This ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3575)

You will get some idea .

Perhaps an option could be passed to EmailField to state whether you want it to lower all case or not. It would save having to do something in the form validation like.

```
def clean_email(self):
    return self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
```